# Regex "SL" Spanish Business - Regex two Characters nothing either side

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a system where users can nput customer information. When the information is enetered I do a few things to clean the information such as changing the case, removing special characters etc. The one issue I have though is that Limited companies have the following syntax, company name:

```
company name SL
```

As I currently change everything to lower case and then use `ucwords` I end up with `Sl`. I am looking for the best way to overcome this and regex sprang to mind.

Unfortunately regex is not my strong point and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. What I am hoping to do is to find the a string that contains two letters `S` and `L` in this order. I need to be able to find the string regardless of characters ie S.L., S.L and also regardless of case. If the string is found, replace this with `SL`.

Within this I would also need to know the characters it found to use string replace to change it.

If you imagine my current method using string replace is growing quite big:

```
return str_replace(array(',','sl.','s.l.','s.l','sl ',' sl','SL.','Sl.','S.L.','S.l.','S.l','S.L','SL'),array("","SL","SL","SL","SL","SL","SL","SL","SL","SL","SL","SL","SL"),self::properCase($name))
```

The issue with the above is also, if some enters say "Bill Slade sl", without a regex to match only those two letters, how could I ever say only upper case them. I need to ensure there is nothing either side.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can the "company name" part contain commas, dots and so forth? Is it ok to remove them?

Comment: I am in the process of stripping the commas as they cause issues when converting the data to csv. To be honest i see no reason why full stops and commas could be removed. I would be interested if there as a way to preserve them in case I am overlooking something, but for now removal would be fine-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this RegEx:

```
/\bs\.?l?\.?\b/i
```

[RegEx Demo and Explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/jJ9kV9/2)

---

Using this RegEx with PHP:

```
$regex_pattern = "/\bs\.?l?\.?\b/i"; 
$string = "company name S.l\ncompany name Sl.\ncompany name S.l.\ncompany name Sl\ncompany name s.l.\ncompany name sl\ncompany name s.L"; 
$replacement  = " SL";
$result = preg_replace($regex_pattern, $replacement, $string);

echo $result;
```

Try this working code on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ so you can see the results quickly. :)

Hope it helps.

---

Read up: [`preg_replace` | PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: This seems to change all instances ie `Robert Slade` becomes `Robert SLade`.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat Yeah, I noticed it. I have updated my code now.

Comment: I have just tested again and everything seems to be working as expected. Many thanks for your time, I really appreciate this. I will have to try and figure out how this works, as i know regex can be seriously powerful, but for some reason it scares the hell out of me. Thanks again +1 for you sir

Comment: @TheHumbleRat Thanks. If you look closely, the dots arent replaced. In that case, the answer by stribizhev is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `\bs[.]?l(?:[.]?|\b)` and substitute with `SL`.

Here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/hB6sF3/1) and [sample working code on TutorialsPoint](http://goo.gl/4nZJEc):

```
$re = "/\\bs[.]?l(?:[.]?|\\b)/i"; 
$str = "company name Sl\ncompany name s.l.\ncompany name sl\ncompany name s.L"; 
$subst = "SL"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$replacement= "SL"; 
$pattern = '/(\bs)(.?)(\s?)(l\b)(.?)/i';

$input = "
  company name Sl
  company name s.l.
  company name sl
  company name s.L
  company name s. L
  company name s l
  company name S, L.
";

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);
echo $result;
```

Go to this  [http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aJi](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aJl) link and click to preg_replace